# Передача данных из одной активити в адаптер из другой активити

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `ListView`, при нажатие на элемент открывается новое активити, там выбираются параметры цвета и размера для элементов листвью, выбираем их и возвращаемся к листьвью,для обработки элементов листьвью создал отдельным классом кастомный адаптер,наследуемый от `ArrayAdapter`, а в нём на работают методы `GetIntent().getExtras()` для получения данных из другой активити, как быть?

Вот код адаптера, нужно в нём получить данные от другой активити.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int myColor,myWidth;
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //  return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ColorTextButton);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.HelpButton);
        textView.setText(values[position]);


        String s = values[position];
        System.out.println(s);
        if (s.equals("Monday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        } else if (s.equals("Wednesday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
            textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        } else if (s.equals("Friday")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызываете `startActivityForResult()` для второй активити, в первой получаете данные и передаете их адаптеру `setData(Color color, int size)` например. В адаптере заводите эти поля, в `getView()` адаптера применяете параметры, в активити после `setData()` вызываете `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Можете , пожалуйста, подробней объяснить как передать адаптеру данные?

Comment: @Mihailenko, создать у адаптера метод `public void setSomeData(List<String> someData) {}`, в котором сделать с полученными данными что душе угодно. И вызывать этот метод там, где адаптеру надо передать данные